# jQuery Flatpickr not working inside cloned element

Tags: jquery, datepicker, append, clone, flatpickr

This is how Flatpickr is loaded:

```
 flatpickr(".ui-date", {
            dateFormat: 'd-m-Y',
        });
```

I'm cloning an element (on button-click):

```
var clone = $('.medereiziger-hidden .sub-form.border.companion').last().clone();
```

Inside this element, there's a datepicker using Flatpickr.

And appending this clone to the page:

```
clone.appendTo($('.medereizigerssection .sub-form.border.companion').last().parent());
```

Now, when I want to use one of the datepickers, the original non-cloned one is working but the clones are not. There's no error in the console log.

How do I fix this?

Code snippet based on @Bhushan Kawadkar his answer:

```js
var uiDate = clone.find(".ui-date");
        if(uiDate){
            flatpickr(uiDate, {
                dateFormat: 'd-m-Y',
            });
        }
```

This is creating the "o.getAttribute is not a function" error (flatpickr, line 2.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call flatpicker again on cloned object as it will not get flatpicker applied automatically

Try below code, but make sure that clone should be same structure as original `.ui-date` html

```
flatpickr(clone, {
            dateFormat: 'd-m-Y',
        });
```

Comment: This is what I have right now, based on your comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/34908f2z/2/) 
But this produces the "o.getAttribute is not a function" error (flatpickr, line 2.)

Comment: can you recreate your issue on code snippet or jsfiddle as i could not see any html on shared link

Comment: See my updated question above. `<input class="ui-date flatpickr-input" type="text" value="22-08-2018" name="medereiziger[954][geboortedatum]" id="f-birthday-3" readonly="readonly">` is the element from `clone.find(".ui-date");`